# How to put the contours in a image numbers? (OCR)

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I've been studying CV for a few months now but I ran into a problem on my second project, I needed to remove the noise from a sequence of numbers, in order to apply ocr. I managed to clean it up, but the numbers lost some internal pixels.

See the initial and  current final image.

[Initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHwKE.png)

[Final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u81uT.png)

Code used:

```
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (15, 15), 2)
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower_gray = np.array([1, 1, 1])
upper_gray = np.array([102, 102, 102])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_gray, upper_gray)

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
opened_mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
masked_img = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask=opened_mask)
coloured = masked_img.copy()
coloured[mask == 0] = (255, 255, 255)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(coloured, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

des = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

contour, hier = cv2.findContours(des, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for cnt in contour:
    cv2.drawContours(des, [cnt], 0, 255, -1)

#des is the final image
```

Is there a better way to clean the background for OCR, or maybe close the lost pixels in the characters?

Comment: If this is one image you need to process, you could do notch filtering, but you you may have to mask the spectrum manually. Your noise is a regular sequence of dots. So the fft spectrum should show an arrangement of dots spaced rather far apart. So only a small number would need to be masked out. This would best be done with some interactive GUI tool such  as GIMP to paint black over the dots in the spectrum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to get a clean background by morphological dilation or closing, a smooth outline by Gaussian filtering, and then binarization. But I found no way to separate the characters.

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you used to do this cleaning?

Comment: @frederick-douglas-pearce: made with proprietary software. But you are not so far.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it, I didn't use the method you mentioned, but it was a good way, I was apprehensive that it would cause an expansion in the characters and wouldn't be good for OCR reading.

[This is my final result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WncC4.png)

```
for mrz in mrz_list:
    try:
        thresh = cv2.threshold(mrz, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

        dist = cv2.distanceTransform(thresh, cv2.DIST_L2, 5)
        dist = cv2.normalize(dist, dist, 0, 1.0, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        dist = (dist * 255).astype("uint8")

        thresh = cv2.threshold(dist, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

        kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
        opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

        cnts = cv2.findContours(opening.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
        cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
        chars = []
        for c in cnts:
            (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
            if w >= 20 and h >= 25:
                chars.append(c)

        chars = np.vstack([chars[i] for i in range(0, len(chars))])
        hull = cv2.convexHull(chars)

        mask = np.zeros(mrz.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [hull], -1, 255, -1)
        mask = cv2.dilate(mask, None, iterations=2)

        final = cv2.bitwise_and(opening, opening, mask=mask)`
```

Thanks everyone.